# In the US, can a college require a student to purchase an access code to turn in homework?

Tags: united-states, books

A friend of mine is attending a nursing program in the state of Washington. I was surprised to learn that her college is forcing everyone in the program to purchase an "e-access code" for a textbook for each class, because the code unlocks access to mandatory online homework. You technically don't have to buy the book itself, but then you won't be able to turn in any assignments.

Is it legal for American colleges to do so — at least if they're publicly funded? Is there some sort of law that a student could use to force the college to accommodate them without forcing them to pay a penny for any materials? Obviously they can still ask whatever they want on homework assignments, but can they flat out refuse to accept your homework solutions if you don't pay?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130361/discussion-on-question-by-jonathanreez-in-the-us-can-a-college-require-a-studen). This is a case where [frame challenges](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4976) or other concerns about the validity of the question itself are probably best addressed in the answers. As always, please avoid answering in the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly normal—and certainly permitted by law—for colleges to require students to purchase things from third-party vendors.  Textbooks are the classic case, although there are clear differences between the situation with traditional textbooks and purely online resources.  (Physical textbooks can be obtained in multiple ways, including for free via sharing, exchanges, etc.)  However, there is also a long history of students needed to pay a specific vendor for a specific product.  Sometimes lab fees work this way, with each student needing to buy a particular lab kit.

Moreover, requiring students to pay for specific online services has become much more common in recent years.  Last year, since my own classes had moved entirely online, I (for the first time) required students to pay for online or in-person test proctoring services.  Personally, I would rather not have done this.  Even though the fee was less than $40 (an relatively insignificant sum compared to the tuition for the course), I would still have preferred not to saddle my students with additional costs.  However, there were not a lot of options, and cheating on tests in the class in question had been a persistent problem, even when the class was held in person.

Comment: Thank you, I've done a lot of research and looks like there's no consumer/student protection law that could apply here. Sounds like colleges may charge whatever they want, any time they want, with the only recourse being to quit the institution.

Comment: It certainly depends on the jurisdiction: I'm pretty sure in Ontario is it illegal to *require* students to buy an e-textbook although not a physical textbook since they can keep the latter and resell it or burn it (whichever they prefer).  It is not illegal to require student to buy the kind of assignment package mentioned by the OP, although students must be able to download or somehow keep a copy of their e-work (hopefully not for reselling).  A student sued over the e-textbook some years (10+) ago, but Google returns nothing and I don't remember so well to do a precise search.

Comment: @JonathanReez: More or less.  The biggest example is that tuition may increase from year to year during the student's time at the university.

Comment: I don't think textbooks are a good analogy, as generally those are available at the library to borrow and thus the students don't actually need to buy them (borrowing might be limited to within the library, or scanning pages from it, but it's still provided/available to the students by the university)